# Error: "No such module" for cocoa pod framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I am using a cocoa pod framework and when I am trying to import that framework then I am getting this error:

Compile time erro: "No such module 'ZLSwipeableViewSwift'".

I am using .xcworkspace to run this iOS app.

These are more detail:

[image]

`UIViewcontroller` in which I am trying to import that module.

[image]

Comment: Quit you Xcode and clean the build then try to rebuild project. or else check in link libraries list the framework is added or not

Comment: clean and try to build again

Answer (score 0):

try cleaning the App using

> command + K

, and then run again!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an issue on this library when installing it via CocoaPods, it is already opened on [the github repo](https://github.com/zhxnlai/ZLSwipeableViewSwift/issues/111).

However, the committer of the repo ([Andrew Breckenridge](https://github.com/AndrewSB)) mentioned:

> for now, you can edit your Podfile to specify the commit that adds
>   swift 4 support:
>
> pod 'ZLSwipeableViewSwift', :git => 'https://github.com/zhxnlai/ZLSwipeableViewSwift.git'

So for now, what you should try to is to add in your podfile:

```
pod 'ZLSwipeableViewSwift', :git => 'https://github.com/zhxnlai/ZLSwipeableViewSwift.git'
```

instead of:

```
pod 'ZLSwipeableViewSwift'
```

and try to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Build the project. Xcode doesn't know about CocoaPod modules until after the first build.